# Split intervals into array such that the elements in each array is non-overlapping

Tags: ios, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects. Each object has a start and an end time. start and end can overlapping, because of that, there should be displayed in different lines. 
the array looks like that:

```
 event1, from 08:00, till 09:00
 event2, from 08:30, till 09:30
 event3, from 09:00, till 10:30
 event4, from 10:00, till 10:30
 event5, from 12:00, till 14:00
```

I want to display them graphically like this:

```
|08:00-09:00|         |10:00-11:00|           |12:00-14:00|
      |08:30-09:30|
            |09:00  -  10:30|
```

I'm trying to sort them so that the result is each line is one array, but I couldn't find the right way.

What's the best way to do that?

EDIT:
thx for all suggestions :-) the following code does the job

```
NSMutableDictionary *allLines = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *firstLine = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[firstLine addObject:[self.tasks objectAtIndex:0]];
[allLines setObject:firstLine forKey:@"1"];

for(int i = 1; i < [self.tasks count]; i++) {
    if (i == [self.tasks count]) {
        break;
    }
    Task *nextTask = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:i];
    for (int j = 1; j <= [allLines count]; j++) {
        NSMutableArray *theArray = [allLines objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",j]];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timerTillHour" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors1 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor1];
        NSArray *sortedArray1 = [theArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors1];

        Task *theTask = [sortedArray1 lastObject];
        if (theTask.timerTillHour+30 > nextTask.timerFromHour) {
            if (j == [allLines count]) {
                NSMutableArray *nextLine = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [nextLine addObject:nextTask];
                [allLines setObject:nextLine forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",j+1]];
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            [theArray addObject:nextTask];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

this results in the following:

[image]

Comment: wouldnt ask if i found a solution, trying it two days :(

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: If you need the minimum number of lines in which such a placement can be made, then I think you will have to take the help of dynamic programming.

Comment: Another (non-greedy) grouping exists, with {8:00,9:00,12:00} on one line and {8:30,10:00} on the second line. That would only need two lines.

Comment: This looks like a variation of the 2D [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). All of your items are size 1 by X, and can only be placed horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's what i would do :

For each object, you need to assign a line (probably a number that correspond to a line) this item will be displayed in. You simply need to assign a line to every item, which you can do in a greedy style algorithm.

In pseudo-language

```
 for each item
      line = 0
      while item.overlap( last_element(line) )
          line = line+1
      item.line = line
```

The idea is that you assign to each item the lowest line it is compatible with.
You will need to store in some way the last element associated to a line (`last_element(line)`). 
When you assign `item.line = line`, you will need to update that last element for `line`. You can use a single dimensional array to do so, of known size because `line` is trivially bounded by the number of items.

This gives a valid configuration. If you want to get the configuration minimising a certain metric (like the number of lines), you won't be able to get away with a greedy algorithm. [Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) might be in order.

Comment: I suggest sorting by start time before applying this. That way, the earlier items will tend to get the earlier lines.

Comment: Yes, I assumed this was already the case as in the exemple data the OP submitted. I should have formulated that out loud.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick Algo for this:

You need a 2d array or a dictionary with array or a new data structur to hold 2 dimentional values

```
create a model with startTime and endTime.


for each event say e
    if array is empty add event
   else{
          read endTime of last object from the array say l
          if e.startTime < l.endTime
                add e above array as a column
          else
                add e to new row

   }
next
```

Comment: A 2-D array is suboptimal for that kind of task. Two 1-D can suffice for storing the relations item->line and line->last_item. See my above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a set of objects (intervals) some of them conflicting with others (i.e. intervals intersect). Consider the intervals to be nodes in a graph and an edge to be present between two nodes, if the corresponding  intervals are intersecting.

Thus the problem reduces to graph colouring with different colours denoting different lines
in the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize number of rows used, you can either implement Dynamic programming solution mentioned above or use algorithms from graph theory.

The problem you described is essentially a version of [vertex-disjoint path cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_cover) for DAGs.

wikipedia has a solution [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Minimum_path_cover_in_directed_acyclic_graph) based on the Bipartite Graph properties. Also, read the last paragraph of the [Airline Scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Airline_scheduling), it is essentially your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by a sweep line algorithm (see http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lineSweep for example). Basically, when a new interval begins, you render the interval at the row with smallest index, not occupied by any interval in the *active set* of the sweep line algorithm.

Sweep line algorithm (pseudocode):

```
struct Interval { double start; double end; }
struct Event { Interval* interval; bool isStart; /* otherwise an end event */ }

vector<Event> events = all start / end events of your interval list
sort(events); // sort all interval points. If they are equal, give
              // priority to start events. This will allow some space
              // between two boxes at the same row.

set<Interval> active_set;
for (Event e : events):
    if (isStartEvent(e)):
        active_set.add(e.interval);
        decide where to draw the interval
    else:
        active_set.remove(e.interval);
```